# Issues using the elements service in console commands

Tags: plugin-development

I'm having trouble getting the elements service working correctly in a consolecommand. The same code works as expected in a controller, so I expect there is either a bug, or some extra config I'm missing.

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class ShoppingCommand extends BaseCommand {

    public function actionListOrders() {
        $c = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
        //$c->locale = craft()->i18n->getPrimarySiteLocale();
        $c->section = 'orders';
        $c->limit = 5;
        foreach($c as $o) {
            print $o->orderId . ": " . $o->title . ", " . $o->price . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

running this results in the following

```
$ ./app/etc/console/yiic shopping listorders
: blah,
```

running the same action with a Controller in the webapp results in the expected output:

```
10: blah, 123
```

Anyone have any ideas if it's possible to get around this? For now I can just build my functionality into a controller, but it would be much more convenient if I could run it from the command line like this.

Also, there is another issue with this relating to the locale. Originally I needed to use the commented out line above because my site's default locale was `en` where as the consolecommands default to `en_us` and without forcing the locale my queries were not returning any results at all. I changed my default locale to `en_us` to test whether the other issue was something to do with the locales as well, but it didn't make a difference.

Cheers

-Tristan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in Craft where custom fields weren't being loaded when using the [ElementsService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/ElementsService) in the context of a console command.

Just fixed it for the next (post [2.2.2598](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2598)) release.

Am I'm not sure I'm following the locale issue.  Can you post that as a separate question with some more clarification?